# Only Allow Mouse and Keyboard USB

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, group-policy

Is there a way (through Group Policy, etc.)
to allow only mouse and keyboards to work via USB ports? 
I would like disable the use of memory sticks or connecting phones, etc.,
to the laptop,
but would like to retain the use of mouse and keyboards as inputs.

Any ideas?

Comment: I copy and pasted your question title in google and this was the first result: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/75255-how-to-restrict-usb-storage-device-without-affecting-usb-keyboard-and-mouse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Open Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc)
> 2. Click Computer Configuration
> 3. Click Policies
> 4. Click Administrative Templates
> 5. Click System
> 6. Click Removable Storage Access
> 7. Enable configuration on the applicable settings:

[image]

> 8. Test it

Reference: [spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/75255-how-to-restrict-usb-storage-device-without-affecting-usb-keyboard-and-mouse)